# Animate gif on scrolling.

Tags: jquery, gif

I have some gifs that want to animated when the user scroll down until their position. 
I am changing the attr src with jquery

```
$(".lazy-load1 img").attr('src',"//pc-resources.xxx.xxxx.com/main/widgets/cms.Gifs/images/duplicate.gif")
```

This partialy works since it does load the pictures, the problem is that they are not playing on page refresh they are only playing the first time or if I go back and hit the front button of my browser. I guess this has something to do with the caching, can I force them to play each time the page is been refreshed.

Answer (score -1):

try changing the attr inside a setTimeout function and add dynamic version to the gif image. Adding dynamic version will avoid it from caching.

```
   setTimeout(function () {
                  $(".lazy-load1 img").attr('src',"//pc-resources.xxx.xxxx.com/main/widgets/cms.Gifs/images/duplicate.gif?version="+Math.random())
                }, 25)
```